# Extract many lines of text in a sheet cell using regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to extract the lines of text without header and upto the line ,,,,,Total

**INPUT**

```
Sr.No ,Description of Goods ,HSN ,,City ,Unit ,,Unit Price ,Amount (in BP) 
1 ,29550762R3C0-Top- ST22E360 ,84439990 ,,1.00 ,Numbers ,,5000.00 ,5000.00 
2 ,29550762R3C0-Bot- ST22E361 ,84439990 ,,1.00 ,Numbers ,,5000.00 ,5000.00 
3 ,2945486609-G2 - Bot Stencil - ST22F199 ,84439990 ,,1.00 ,Numbers ,,5000.00 ,5000.00 
4 ,2945457600-S1 - Top Stencil - ST22F224 ,84439990 ,,1.00 ,Numbers ,,5000.00 ,5000.00 
5 ,2945457600-G2 - Bot Stencil - ST22F225 ,84439990 ,,1.00 ,Numbers ,,5000.00 ,5000.00 
,,,,,Total ,,,25000.00 IN 
,,,,,Discount ,,,0.00 3 
,,,,Total Amount ,Before Tax ,,,"₹ 25,000.00 "
,,,,,IGST 0% ,,,₹ 0.00 
,,,,Total Amount ,After Tax: ,,,"₹ 25,000.00 "
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
1 ,29550762R3C0-Top- ST22E360 ,84439990 ,,1.00 ,Numbers ,,5000.00 ,5000.00 
2 ,29550762R3C0-Bot- ST22E361 ,84439990 ,,1.00 ,Numbers ,,5000.00 ,5000.00 
3 ,2945486609-G2 - Bot Stencil - ST22F199 ,84439990 ,,1.00 ,Numbers ,,5000.00 ,5000.00 
4 ,2945457600-S1 - Top Stencil - ST22F224 ,84439990 ,,1.00 ,Numbers ,,5000.00 ,5000.00 
5 ,2945457600-G2 - Bot Stencil - ST22F225 ,84439990 ,,1.00 ,Numbers ,,5000.00 ,5000.00
```

I have tried with: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A10,"(\n.*)")`, The number of lines are not known in advance and can vary from cell to cell. Some may have one and some have 5 to 6.

Comment: Can't you just match lines with `^\d+\s*,` ?

Comment: @anubhava, Hi anubhava, Just FYI please!! I have come to know from Jvdv that since values are in single cell then this may not work.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples Only, please try following solutions. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/teRPmB/1) for shown regex.

***Google sheet formula with regex:*** THANKS to @Jvdv for such a nice formula, credit to him for throwing light on this one.

`=FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"((?:\n[0-9]+\s+,[0-9a-zA-Z]+-.*?-.*?,[0-9]+(?:.*?,){2}[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s+,Numbers\s+(?:.*?,){2}[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s+,[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\b\s?)+)"),CHAR(10),1,1))`

---

---

***Only regex solution:*** Where we can use regex inside `REGEXEXTRACT` function but since it generates only 1 capturing group so keeping whole regex into one capturing group and then we need to split it with new lines, which is why ABOVE solution is kept as an whole solution.

```
(^[0-9]+\s+,[0-9a-zA-Z]+-.*?-.*?,[0-9]+(?:.*?,){2}[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s+,Numbers\s+(?:.*?,){2}[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s+,[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\b)
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
(                   ##starting main capturing group.
^[0-9]+\s+,         ##Matching digits from starting of value followed by spaces followed by comma.
[0-9a-zA-Z]+-       ##Matching alphanumeric 1 or more occurrences followed by -
.*?-.*?,            ##Using Lazy match till - followed by another lazy match till comma.
[0-9]+              ##Matching digits 1 or more occurrences here.
(?:.*?,){2}         ##In a non-capturing group using lazy match till comma with its 2 occurrences.
[0-9]+              ##Matching digits 1 or more occurrences here.
(?:\.[0-9]+)?       ##Followed by dot followed by 1 or more digits to handle float matches keeping it optional.
\s+,                ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of spaces followed by comma.
Numbers\s+          ##Matching string Numbers followed by spaces 1 or more occurrences.
(?:.*?,){2}         ##In a non-capturing group matching till comma and making its 2 occurrences.
[0-9]+              ##Matching digits 1 or more occurrences here.
(?:\.[0-9]+)?       ##Followed by dot followed by 1 or more digits to handle float matches keeping it optional.
\s+,                ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of spaces followed by comma.
[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)? ##Matching 1 or more digits followed by dot followed by 1 or more digits to handle float matches keeping it optional.
\b                  ##Using word boundary to make sure previous match it exact match.
)                   ##closing opened capturing group in starting.
```

Comment: unfortunately https://prnt.sc/GyMNd_nwbfHQ this didnt help.

Comment: @CodeGuy, ok sure, let me take a look to it. Meanwhile just a question, you want to match exactly same number of commas with strings in between like I matched right?

Comment: @CodeGuy, please try my updated regex(though code from Jvdv is a good one), my edited code(thanks to jvdv for regexextract guidance) will work but then later on we need to split it's output by new lines. Kindly try this out and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: @JvdV, yeah sure I just noticed, so that's because values are in same cell. So can't we use multiline here? I read googling that `?s` flag could be used for multiline, just confirming here.

Comment: `=FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?m)((?:^[0-9]+\s+,[0-9a-zA-Z]+-.*?-.*?,[0-9]+(?:.*?,){2}[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s+,Numbers\s+(?:.*?,){2}[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s+,[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\b\s*)+)$"),CHAR(10)))` would make it such that you also don't need to use the last two parameters of `SPLIT()` nomore since we used the `\s*` and end-line anchor `$`. I think that's now all good =)

Comment: @JvdV, That's awesome. One more question(Sorry to bug you), how you have installed Google sheets(personal one)? I have been trying but its giving me only for trail version, is there any free version if not then paid one(without asking a domain name). Will be grateful if you could guide me on same, thank you.

Comment: I just use the browser version with my google account. Was not even aware you can download sheets.

Comment: @JvdV, oh ok, let me try with my Google account also once, cheers.

Comment: @CodeGuy, could you please do let me know if this solution has worked for you, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents, assuming:

- Each line of interest starts with a digit;
- You'd like to actually spill each line of interest down.

[image]

Formula in `A3`:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1,CHAR(10))),"where Col1 matches '^\d.+'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply match the lines which start with digits,space,comma till the end of line:

```
/^\d+ *,.*$/gm
```

[Demo on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5Iv6fY/1)

```
^    Start of line
\d+  One or more digits
 *   Zero or more spaces
,    Comma
.*   Any character
$    End of line

/gm  Flags: Global; Multi line
```